# "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" while trying to access spotify api

Tags: python, data-analysis, spotipy

I am trying to use Spotify's web API to collect user's top tracks and artists. However I am encountering the error in the title. I have added the redirect_uri inn my app too.
Please help.

```
import os
import json
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy.util as util
cid ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID']= cid
os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET']= secret
os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI']='http://localhost:8888/callback'
username = "31wd5m45dkipm2hrmgjwflkgusq4"
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
scope = 'user-top-read'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```